# Does there exist positive rational $s$ for which $\zeta(s)$ is a positive integer?

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

> Does there exist positive rational $s$ for which the Riemann Zeta function $\zeta(s) \in N$ or equivalently, does there exist finite positive integers $\ell,m$ and $n$ such that $$\zeta\left(1+\dfrac{\ell}{m}\right) = n$$

**Update: 23-Mar-2023**: New and faster code using hash map. Using this code and the method described in my answer below, I have been able to show that if there is a solution then $l > 1.7\times 10^5$.

```
def get_n_value(a,b):
    c_b = (b/a).n(prec = prec)
    return max(2, -1 + floor(0.07281584548367672486058637587/(eg - c_b)))

def get_c_value(m):
    i   = 1
    c_m = 0
    while (i <= itr):
        c_m = (m + c_m - zeta(1 + 1/(m - 1 + c_m))).n(prec = prec)
        i = i + 1
    return c_m

def get_next_b(c_n1,b):
    b_prev = b
    b = 1 + floor(c_n1*a)
    if b <= b_prev:
        b = b_prev + 1
    if gcd(a,b) > 1:
        b = b + 1 
    return b

a = 1 
step = 10^1
target = a + step - 1
sd = 0

prec = 1500
n_max = 0 
eg = (1 - euler_gamma).n(prec = prec)
itr = 50
# c_dict = {}
c_2 = get_c_value(2)
 

while True:
    c_n1 = c_2
    b = 1 + floor(c_2*a)
    b_max = floor(eg*a)
    depth = 0
    
    while(b <= b_max):
        if(gcd(b,a) == 1):
            found = False
            test = b/a.n(prec = prec)
            n = get_n_value(a,b)
            
            if n in c_dict:
                c_n = c_dict.get(n)
            else:
                c_n = get_c_value(n)
                c_dict[n] = c_n
                
            while found == False:
            
                if (n+1) in c_dict:
                    c_n1 = c_dict.get(n+1)
                else:
                    c_n1 = get_c_value(n+1)
                    c_dict[n+1] = c_n1

                if c_n < test and test < c_n1:
                    found = True
                    depth  = depth + 1

                    if (n > n_max):
                        n_max = n
                        # print("Maximum n is at:", a, b, n_max)
                        
                    # print('found',a,b,'witness =',n)
                    break
                else:
                    c_n = c_n1
                    n = n + 1
                    
            b = get_next_b(c_n1,b)
            
            if(b > b_max):
                break
        else:
            b = get_next_b(c_n1,b)
            if(b > b_max):
                break

    sd = sd + depth
    
    if a == target:
        l = len(c_dict)
        print(a,'dict', l,l/a.n(), 'dep', depth, 'sd',sd, sd/a.n())
        target = target + step

    a = a + 1
```

Comment: I would expect that $\zeta(r)$ is irrational for all rationals $r > 1$, but to prove this may be beyond the current state of the art.  We don't even know that $\zeta(5)$ is irrational.

Comment: If $\zeta$ denotes the Riemann zeta function, please include it in your question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Can you resolve the problem for any other value of l, other than l=1?
> For example, can you resolve the case l=2?

Yes and in fact I can show that there is no solution for $l \le 3*10^4$. Here is the outline of my approach which I am posting as an answer since it is too long to be a comment.

**Step 1**: The first step was to derive the following result

> For every real $x \ge 1$ there exists a positive real $c_x$ such
> that ${\displaystyle{ \zeta\Big(1+\frac{1}{x-1+c_x}\Big) = x. }}$
>
> The first few terms of the asymptotic expansion of $c_x$ in terms of $n$ and the Stieltjes constants $\gamma_i$ are
>
> $$ c_x = 1-\gamma_0 + \frac{\gamma_1}{x-1} 
>  + \frac{\gamma_2 + \gamma_1 - \gamma_0 \gamma_1}{(x-1)^2}
> + \frac{\gamma_2 +2\gamma_2 - 2\gamma_2 \gamma_0 + \gamma_1 - 2\gamma_1 \gamma_0 + \gamma_1 \gamma_0^2 - \gamma_1^2}{(x-1)^3}
> + O\Big(\frac{1}{x^4}\Big) $$

**Step 2:** I computed the first few values of $c_n$ but I did not use the above result. Instead I used the following recurrence formula.

> Let $\alpha_0$ be any positive real and  ${\displaystyle{ \alpha_{r+1} = n +
> \alpha_r - \zeta\Big(1+\frac{1}{n -1 + \alpha_r}\Big); }}$ then ${\displaystyle{ \lim_{r \to \infty}\alpha_r = c_n}}$.

Using this we obtained
$$
c_2 \approx 0.3724062
$$
$$
c_3 \approx 0.3932265
$$
$$
\ldots
$$
$$
c_{12} \approx 0.4164435
$$

**Step 3:** Show that $l \ge 5$

Let ${\displaystyle{ \zeta\Big(1+\frac{l}{m}\Big) \in N}}$ and let $m = lk+d$ where $\gcd(l,d) = 1$ and $1 \le d < l$.

Clearly, $c_2 \le c_n < 1-\gamma_0$ or $0.3724062 \le c_n < 0.422785$.
Hence we must have ${\displaystyle{ 0.3724062 \le \frac{d}{l} < 0.422785}}$. The fraction with the smallest value of $l$ satisfying this condition is ${\displaystyle{\frac{2}{5} }}$ hence $l \ge 5$.

Extending this approach using numerical computations, I am able to show that there is no solution for $l < 3*10^4$.

**Problems with this approach:**

With this approach and with powerful computing, we can prove results like if ${\displaystyle{  \zeta\Big(1+\frac{l}{m}\Big) \in N }}$ then $l$ must be greater than some large positive integer but I don't see how this approach will solve the general problem.

Comment: Nice work! Seems like a lot of progress. Is this your own problem?

Comment: Thanks. Yes its my own problem that I worked way back in 2005 and then it got lost among other things. Revisiting it now after 13 years.

Comment: This certainly seems worth publishing. Here is one possibility: https://www.tandfonline.com/loi/uexm20

Answer (score 21):

I misread $l$ as $1$, but in any case, as a partial result, here's a resolution for the case $l=1$.

Fix $s\in\mathbb{R}$, with $s > 1$.

On the interval $(0,\infty)$, let 
$f(x)={\small{{\displaystyle{\frac{1}{x^{\large{s}}}}}}}$.

It's easily verified that 
$
{\displaystyle{
\int_{1}^\infty \!f(x)\,dx
=
{\small{\frac{1}{s-1}}}
}}
$.

Consider the infinite series 
$
{\displaystyle{
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^s}
}}
$.

Since $f$ is positive, continuous, and strictly decreasing, we get
\begin{align*}
\int_{1}^\infty \!f(x)\,dx < \;&\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^s} < 1+\int_{1}^\infty \!f(x)\,dx\\[4pt]
\implies\;{\small{\frac{1}{s-1}}} < \;&\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^s} < 1+{\small{\frac{1}{s-1}}}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
If $m$ is a positive integer, then letting $s=1+{\large{\frac{1}{m}}}$, we have ${\large{\frac{1}{s-1}}}=m$, hence
\begin{align*}
{\small{\frac{1}{s-1}}} < \;&\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^s} < \;1+{\small{\frac{1}{s-1}}}\\[4pt]
\implies\;m < \;\,&\zeta\bigl(1+{\small{\frac{1}{m}}}\bigr) < \;m + 1\\[4pt] 
\end{align*}
so  $\zeta\bigl(1+{\large{\frac{1}{m}}}\bigr)$ is not an integer.

Comment: Thanks. In fact I have a slightly stronger result can be one of the approach to tackle this problem. Using the Stieltjes series expansion of thte Riemann Zeta function we can show that for $l = 1$, the fractional part of $\zeta(1+1/m)$ starts from $\pi^2/2 - 1 = 0.6449341$ for $m = 1$ and strictly decreases with $m$ and approaches the limiting value of $1-\gamma \sim 0.422785$ where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant. Hence $\pi^2/2 - 1 \le (\zeta(1+1/m)) \le \gamma$. I have been trying to see if this method can be generalized for the case $l > 1$.

Comment: Yes, I had that result, but it doesn't go anywhere for $l > 1$.

Comment: Can you resolve the problem for any other value of $l$, other than $l=1$? For example, can you resolve the case $l=2$?

Comment: Note that for positive integers $l,m$, the expression $1+l/m$ can take any rational value greater than $1$, so your question can be recast as asking if there exists a rational number $s > 1$ such that $\zeta(s)$ is an integer. My sense (seconding Robert Israel's comment) is that an answer to that question is out of range of current knowledge.

Comment: I think that the case for integer should be easier than the case for deciding rationality. I will outline my approach below since it will be too long for a comment.

Answer (score 6):

Whilst not a solution, I thought it might be interesting to see What happens if we use the functional equation:

$$\zeta\left(1+\frac{m}{n}\right)=2^{\left(1+\frac{m}{n}\right)}\pi^{\frac{m}{n}}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\left(1+\frac{m}{n}\right)\right)\Gamma\left(-\frac{m}{n}\right)\zeta\left(-\frac{m}{n}\right).$$

$\zeta(s)$ is known to be rational at the negative integers,

$$\zeta(-a)=(-1)^a\frac{B_{a+1}}{a+1}.$$

You actually get $\zeta(-a)=0$ for $a$ even due to the trivial zeros.

But it appears that when you combine this with the functional equation, then in the limit, you get something non-zero and irrational, so that doesn't even give you an integer.

On the other hand if $m/n=2k-1$ is odd then we have

$$\zeta\left(2k\right)=\frac{(-1)^{k+1}B_{2k}(2\pi)^{2k}}{2(2k)!},$$

by Euler's formula, which is "almost" rational except for the $\pi$ factor. Bugger. So no chance of being integral.

If you modify your problem slightly, then using the above you can produce positive integers, but that's no fun.